# postgresql, xpath query and cdata elements as plain text

Tags: postgresql

I have an xml field containing elements with CDATA. Can i use xpath and have only the inner text (without `<![CDATA[ ]>`?

```
# select xpath('/Product/DescriptiveDetail/TitleDetail/TitleElement/TitleText/text()', onix) as title from books;
                title
--------------------------------------
 {"<![CDATA[The name of the rose]]>"}
```

Comment: You have the data. Did you try, what result did you get? What is your query, on what data?

Comment: i posted a snippet of the query within the question

Comment: Hey, I've just tested: `# SELECT xpath('/TitleText/text()', '<TitleText><![CDATA[The name of the rose]]></TitleText>');` and got `{"The name of the rose"}`. I use PostgreSQL 10.3, what is your version? Can you post test data?

Comment: http://paste.debian.net/plain/1128912

Comment: See [BUG #16046: xpath returns CDATA tag along with the value in postgres 12](http://micronetinternational.com/index.pl/en/00/https/www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-16046-xpath-returns-CDATA-tag-along-with-the-value-in-postgres-12-td6106955.html).

Comment: @Adam I guess you meant to link https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/16046-a04d0611e7a0c03a@postgresql.org